# Tela de conexão do adminMongo

Tags: mongodb

Instalei o adminMongo.

Segui as [instruções de instalação](https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo):

> 1. Navigate to folder & install adminMongo: git clone https://github.com/mrvautin/adminMongo.git && cd adminMongo
> 2. Install dependencies: npm install
> 3. Start application: npm start or node app
> 4. Visit http://127.0.0.1:1234 in your browser

Até chegar na página de login da etapa (4) e de lá eu não consegui passar.

Eu preciso preencher o campo `"Connection string"`, mas eu não sei o que devo setar lá.

EDIT: Me refiro a esta string aqui:

```
mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:<port>/<db>
```

Alguém pode me explicar? Obrigado!

Comment: Está falando dessa *string* `mongodb://<user>:<password>@127.0.0.1:<port>/<db>`? Seja mais claro no seu problema.

Comment: Exatamente! Essa string mesmo! Vou melhorar a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *string* de conexão é bem descritiva, sobre o que precisa conter. São os dados de autenticação do seu banco (*MongoDB*) **o qual você vai *linkar* com o *AdminMongo***.

**Supondo** que você tenha o *MongoDB* configurado na sua máquina, os dados são:

- `<user>` = usuário
- `<password>` = senha
- `127.0.0.1` = endereço do servidor para conexão (*no seu caso é o local: 127.0.0.1*)
- `<port>` = porta (*opcional, a porta padrão é a 27017*)
- `<db>` = banco (*isso é opcional, o banco default é o admin*)

Na [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) oficial você tem a descrição detalhada da *string* de conexão.

Comment: Esses parametros eu entendi! O problema é que tudo o que eu coloco lá pra fazer a conexão resulta em erro. Digitei o seguinte: "mongodb://root:@127.0.0.1". Resposta: "Config error: MongoError: Authentication failed."

Comment: @JHenry edita sua pergunta e adiciona essas informações, daí fica melhor de entender. E esse erro é bem descritivo, você está errando algum desses parâmetros.

Comment: Eu consegui resolver! Desculpe o amadorismo da pergunta. Mas, apesar de simples, há tantas opções possíveis, com ou sem aspas, com ou sem dois pontos, com ou sem parâmetros opcionais. Tem que ter uma bola de cristal pra descobri o jeito certo. Mas obrigado!!!